# Dustum Khan's quest

Tags: mount-and-blade

What is Dustum Khan's quest like?  I'm assuming you battle Khergit lords, convert them to your side, and then battle more Khergit lords.  Right?

I ask because my strategy requires eliminating Khergit Khanate, but I hate fighting them myself.  I'd love to weaken them via civil war, but not if this quest involves lots of fighting Khergit Horsemen.  I figured I'd ask you all before leaving King Ragnar's favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how much influence you have over the Khergit lords, you may be able to get them to join your rebellion without ever having to fight a mounted battle against them. You'd still have to capture their cities however, and once you've destroyed the old faction I don't remember there being any way to prevent the Khan from taking the faction over along with all your acquired territories.

If you're already in the Nords' favour, influence Ragnar to go to war with the Khergit and just avoid land battles but help sieges, that's probably a lot easier.

Comment: Okay.  So I would convert Khergit enemies to allies by talking to them?  I like attacking cities, but get bored with the "Nord turtle-shell" strategy I have to use on the open plains.  Ultimately, I'd like to start a civil war within the Khanate, then walk away and let them kill each other.  I'm more than happy to fail the quest, so long as the Khanate destroys itself.

Comment: I don't think the Khanate would destroy itself. If you're playing the original M&B, I'm not sure how it handles failing the quest. The lords may simply return to the faction they've left which would leave you off no further. Or you could stop short of completely annihilating the Khanate and simply keep Dustum in your party for the rest of time. The other factions like the Swadians and Vaegirs may be more useful as they're more aggressive though, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I took Dustum Khan's quest about 2 (in-game) months ago.  I tracked down the Khergit lords, either in their castles, or outnumbering them on the battlefield, and talked to them.  6 converted to my side, while 12 refused.

Ironically, I now spend even more time fighting those loathsome Khergit Horsemen.  To compensate, I've changed my army composition to 100% cavalry.  Battles are simpler now;  everyone just charges the entire time.  It's not as intricate as the Hold/Follow/Charge/Repeat strategy I used with my Nord Turtleshell, but it's effective.